# Column Totaling

Tags: javascript, html

I need it to update the column totals when the row updates so I assume I can add it into the current script but I am in over my head.

I am using the below script to total the rows:

```
<script>
function total_amount(){
        var table = document.getElementById('line_item');
        for(var i=1;i<table.rows.length;i++){
            qty = table.rows[i].cells[1].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            unit = table.rows[i].cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value
            table.rows[i].cells[3].getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value = qty * unit;
        }
    }
</script>
```

I am looking to do the same with the column that this script returns. I have attempted and failed to convert this to a column script, I tried several different totaling scripts but since I need it to update after the user updates their part I seem to keep breaking it.

My table

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="line_item" data-togle="table" data-sort-stable="true">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        Product
      </th>
      <th>
        Quantity
      </th>
      <th>
        Price Unit
      </th>
      <th>
        Amount
      </th>
<th>
Date of Service
</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  
  <tbody>
<tr>
      <td id="col0">
[select SERVICES1]</td>
      <td id="col1">
        [number Quantity onblur="total_amount()"]
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="unit" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
      <td id="col3" class="count-me">
        [number amount]
      </td>
<td>[date DOS1]</td>    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
       [select SERVICES2]
      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        [number Quantity2 onblur="total_amount()"]
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="unit2" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
      <td id="col3" class="count-me">
        [number amount2 readonly]
      </td>
<td>[date DOS2]</td>    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
[select SERVICES3]      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        [number Quantity3 onblur="total_amount()"]
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="unit3" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
      <td id="col3" class="count-me">
        [number amount3 readonly]
      </td>
<td>[date DOS3]</td>    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td id="col0">
  [select SERVICES4]
      </td>
      <td id="col1">
        [number Quantity4 onblur="total_amount()"]
      </td>
      <td id="col2">
        <input class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Price Unit" id="unit4" onblur="total_amount()">
      </td>
```

Comment: Initialize a total variable for each column to `0` before the loop, e.g. `let total_quantity = 0;`. Inside the loop, add each value from the current row to the corresponding total variable, e.g. `total_quantity += parseFloat(qty);`. At the end, put these totals in the totals row of the table.